# Dynamic size, two column layout with one column vertically and horizontally aligned, legacy browser support

Tags: css

I am trying to create a two column layout, with content in column 1 both horizontally and vertically aligned in the middle, whereby the content of column 2 will vary in size.  The width of both columns is fixed to 50% of the width of the screen.

In modern CSS complaint browsers I can simply do the following:

CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;

    /* for illustration purposes */
    background: #ddd;
}

#left-column
{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    /* for illustration purposes */
    background: #fdd;
}

#right-column
{
    display: table-cell;

    /* for illustration purposes */
    background: #ddf;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left-column">
        <p>I am both horizontally and vertically centered in column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
        <p>I am dynamic content in column 2, i.e. my size will vary</p>
        <p>I am dynamic content in column 2, i.e. my size will vary</p>
        <p>I am dynamic content in column 2, i.e. my size will vary</p>
        <p>I am dynamic content in column 2, i.e. my size will vary</p>
        <p>I am dynamic content in column 2, i.e. my size will vary</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the bad news is I also need this to work in IE6, and IE7...

The solutions I've seen so far are quite ugly and involve lots of nested divs.  What's the cleanest way to achieve this so that it will work in all browsers?  I've experimented with float: left, for the two column layout, but my main problem is the vertical alignment in the first column.

PS. I don't want to use tables for the layout, although it does work, it's bad for screen readers and therefore breaks my accessibility guidelines.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your left-column only going to have one line (of text), all the time?

Comment: The left hand column will actually contain an image, and two lines of text, where the image is vertically centered to the left of the two lines of text.  The above was a simplified example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With static content on the left-hand column, your solution is simple: use fixed heights and `padding`.

**CSS**

```
#left-column {
    height: 50%; /* adjust height dependent on N&S padding */
    padding: 20% 0; /* adds north and south padding to "center" #left-content */
}
#left-content {
    height: 10%; /* adjust to exactly fit content */
    text-align: center;

    /* basically for testing, this will help us find the ideal
     * percentage for our #left-content height. */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="left-column">

    <div id="left-content">

        your image and text goes here

    </div><!-- /left-content -->

</div><!-- /left-column -->
```

In your CSS, you will need to adjust the heights and paddings to achieve your desired result.

I would suggest ensuring the content in #left-content is 100% responsive. This may not be a 100% solution, but with some work on it (@media queries, etc), you should be able to achieve your goal in every browser and viewport size. The only thing I can think of off the top of my head that *might* break something like this is user-increased font size.

Comment: Hi Vonkly, thanks for this, but I can't quite get it to work - with the left-column floated the height: 50% doesn't do anything.

Comment: You should use `display: inline-block;` instead of floating elements, if you just need two stacked. While `float` achieves your goal, it's unnecessary. See if that fixes your problem. Can you link me to your live test?

Comment: display: inline-block; isn't supported in IE6, float: left seems to be the way to go for two column layout according to these guys: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/two-fixed/

Comment: I found a nice workaround for IE6 and display: inline-block, so accepting this as the answer since it lead me down the right path.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Hey Tony - sorry for the late reply, I haven't been on SO for a few days. Glad I could help you find the answer. Posting your workaround might be helpful to future readers!

Comment: Hey Vonkly, sorry I only just noticed this in my inbox! - the work around is I created a javascript IE compatibility script that I use conditional statements to include for browsers less than IE8.  If I detect the browser version is IE6 I iterate over all the div elements in the DOM and if they have a style of display:inline-block, set it to display:inline.  Setting it twice in this way gives the element "layout" and makes it act a lot like display:inline-block in IE6.  Quirky but it seems to work :-) I'll be glad when no-one on the planet is using IE6 any more ;-)

Comment: Tony - can't believe I didn't mention this. You can use both `float: left;` and `display: inline-block;` on your container elements; this should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately vertically centering something is either going to take javascript or a few ugly nested divs. If you are a maniacal purist I would recommend a float left, top aligned left column and enhance with javascript to be pushed to center.

That said, a couple wrapper divs never killed anyone.

Comment: It depends on the content in the left div. If it's static and won't change (ie, always be a set number of lines of copy), then he could simply use `height`, `line-height` and/or `padding` to easily overcome his issue.

Comment: You are correct, but it is pretty rare that you are vertically centering something and want to specify an absolute `height` value on an element.

Answer (score 0):

Cracked it, I think... Html as in the original post, and CSS as follows:

```
#wrapper
{
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    /* for illustration purposes */
    background: #ddd;
}

#wrapper p { font-size:1em; margin: .5em; }

#right-column
{
    margin-left: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* for illustration purposes */
    background: #ddf;
}

#left-column
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -1em;
    text-align: center;

    /* for illustration purposes */
    background: #fdd;
}
```

The margin on the inner <p> tag needs setting so that we know what the height will be (the different browsers seem to default the margin of a <p> differently if you don't explicitly set it), I used em so that it scales nicely on different displays.

It's funny how something this simple can be such a pain to achieve... I'm still not 100% happy with it as if the content of column 1 wraps on a small display (or minimised window), then it won't be vertically aligned properly...